# Univariate maximization of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a factored polynomial

$$f(x) = \prod_{i} (x - r_i)$$

such that $r_i \in \mathbb{R}~\backslash~(0,1)$. The polynomial has a degree of the order $10^4$. I hope to find the value of $x$ which maximizes $f(x)$ such that $x \in [0, 1]$.

I can't think of an analytic solution. One non-analytic approach is solving $f'(x) = 0$ approximately and substituting each root in $f(x)$, but I feel the large degree of polynomial $f$ makes this solution computationally expensive. I have two questions:

1. What is the best algorithm to solve this problem approximately?
2. Is it possible to solve this problem analytically?

Comment: Let $g(x) = \log f(x) = \sum_i \log|x-r_i|$. Conveniently, this is concave on $[0,1]$, so its derivative is monotonic. Find the zero of $g'(x)$ using bisection search (or Newton's method to go faster).

Comment: All roots $r_1\leq r_2\leq \ldots \leq r_n$ are real, and the derivative has one less root. Hence by rolles theorem the roots of the derivative $s_i$ are $r_1\leq s_1\leq r_2\leq s_2 \leq r_3\leq \ldots \leq r_n$, so the derivative has at most one root on $(0,1)$.

Hence the polynomial is somewhere between monotonous and unimodal, so the optimization is very simple.